# Set product stock quantity after uncancelling order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, stock, edit-order, manage-stock

I have a module to uncancel orders. The problem is that when I uncancel an order, the stock quantity is not decreasing for the amount of items ordered. I have the line of code that set order back to previous state. I am trying to decrease the stock without success. Here is my code.

```
foreach ( $order->getItemsCollection() as $item ) {
                $item->setQtyCanceled( 0 );
                $item->setTaxCanceled( 0 );
                $item->setHiddenTaxCanceled( 0 );

                $item->getData('qty_ordered');
                $item->getData();
                $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
                $stockItem->assignProduct($item);
                $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
                $stockItem->setData('qty', 1);
                $item->setStockItem($stockItem);
                $item->save();
            }
```

I am getting this error:
 Call to a member function getWebsiteId() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status.php on line 208

and the item qty is not set to "1" ( "1" for test purpose)

Does anyone have an idea on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

on line 208 of `\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status.php`, there is a call `$product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()`.

This is called in the method `assignProduct` declared as :

```
public function assignProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $stockId = 1, $stockStatus = null)
```

First param has to be an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and your `$item` is an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`.

So, instead of passing `$item` as a first parameter, you should try to pass `$item->getProduct()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does solve the php error, but still do not work to reduce item stock.